# Por que os construtores tem que ter o mesmo nome da classe?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, característica-linguagem, construtor

Será que é mesmo necessário o construtor ter o mesmo nome que a classe?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Sim, é. A linguagem exige isso por convenção. Poderia não ser, mas é assim.

[Documentação](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class). [Também](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor). [Documentação da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constructors-cpp?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=msvc-160). Se a especificação fosse publicada abertamente eu postaria aqui, mas o trecho do item 12.1 seria:

> Constructors do not have names. A special declarator syntax is used to declare or define the constructor.

Então essa é a sintaxe adotada por convenção, embora formalmente ele não tenha um nome oficial.

Isso vale para todas linguagens que eu conheço que possuem o mecanismo de construtor.

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente é o método chamado quando você constrói aquele objeto, no exemplo

```java
Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
```

o `new` chama o construtor da classe Cliente, construindo o objeto desejado e atribuindo a varíavel. O uso dessa forma é uma convenção acredito, a visibilidade é melhor. No javascript usasse a palavra `constructor` e em PHP usasse `__construct` como o construtor da classe, mostrando que não é uma coisa padronizada para todas.